# Regular Expression Lookbehind doesn't work with quantifiers ('+' or '*')

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I am trying to use lookbehinds in a regular expression and it doesn't seem to work as I expected. So, this is not my real usage, but to simplify I will put an example. Imagine I want to match "example" on a string that says "this is an example". So, according to my understanding of lookbehinds this should work:

```
(?<=this\sis\san\s*?)example
```

What this should do is find "this is an", then space characters and finally match the word "example". Now, it doesn't work and I don't understand why, is it impossible to use '+' or '*' inside lookbehinds?

I also tried those two and they work correctly, but don't fulfill my needs:

```
(?<=this\sis\san\s)example
this\sis\san\s*?example
```

I am using this site to test my regular expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: This needs a tag that identifies the language or environment where you use them. .NET's regular expressions handle this without a problem.

Comment: Notice! If your regex would work like you want it will also match `example` from this: `this is anexample`. So if you don't want that you should remove the `?`

Comment: micha: They should probably just change the * to a `+`. Removing the `?` has no effect in that regard. But indeed, `*?` as a quantifier is useless and unnecessary in this case as there isn't any more whitespace to match after that, so `\s*?` is equivalent to `\s*`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Many regular expression libraries do only allow strict expressions to be used in look behind assertions like:

- only match strings of the same fixed length: `(?<=foo|bar|\s,\s)` (three characters each)
- only match strings of fixed lengths: `(?<=foobar|\r\n)` (each branch with fixed length)
- only match strings with a upper bound length: `(?<=\s{,4})` (up to four repetitions)

The reason for these limitations are mainly because those libraries can’t process regular expressions backwards at all or only a limited subset.

Another reason could be to avoid authors to build too complex regular expressions that are heavy to process as they have a so called [pathological behavior](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) (see also [ReDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS)).

See also [section about limitations of look-behind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) on [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: In [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286667/regular-expression-using-negative-lookbehind-not-working-in-notepad/48727748#48727748), I have listed some strategies/workarounds after I ran into this limitation on negative lookbehinds. Hope it can help some others too!

Comment: For Python, third-party [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package which allows variable width patterns on look-behind. [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987519)

Answer (score 18):

Hey if your not using python variable look behind assertion you can trick the regex engine by escaping the match and starting over by using `\K`.

This site explains it well .. http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k ..

But pretty much when you have an expression that you match and you want to get everything behind it using \K will force it to start over again...

Example:

```
string = '<a this is a tag> with some information <div this is another tag > LOOK FOR ME </div>'
```

matching `/(\<a).+?(\<div).+?(\>)\K.+?(?=\<div)/`  will cause the regex to restart after you match the ending `div` tag so the regex won't include that in the result.  The `(?=\div)` will make the engine get everything in front of ending div tag

Comment: this works with ruby 2.x but fails with 1.9 and jruby 1.7.x; original comment: good one, I'm surprised I never knew this feature. Learn to format code in the editor and you'll be priceless

Answer (score 11):

What Amber said is true, but you can work around it with another approach: A non-capturing parentheses group

```
(?<=this\sis\san)(?:\s*)example
```

That make it a *fixed* length look behind, so it should work.

Comment: It's the same like `(?<=this\sis\san)\s*?example` that means that it also match the spaces and for your information `(?:` `)` makes the process slower.

Comment: micha, I'd worry more about the matching part in that case than about performance. I get on average 0.02451781 ms with the non-capuring group and 0.02370844 ms without it. I don't think that's a significant difference.

Comment: @micha No. It is not the same. It's a *non-capturing* group. My regex only matches `example` (without the leading spaces), but your example *includes* leading spaces

Comment: This regex will match any preceding spaces. eg `this is an[        example]`. (square brackets represent a match). Just because it is in a non-capturing group, doesn't mean it isn't matched. It just means it isn't captured in a group which would normally be captured in normal brackets. The right way to do this would be using `\K` like @Leon said

Comment: This doesn't work. Leading spaces are included in the match. Just copy and paste it in https://regex101.com/.

Comment: @alstr In my test of this for matching an unknown scheme and remaining URL, this does not match on leading spaces on regex101 `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9].*:\/\/)([a-zA-Z09-_].*\/+)$`

Answer (score 2):

You can use sub-expressions.

```
(this\sis\san\s*?)(example)
```

So to retrieve group 2, "example", `$2` for regex, or `\2` if you're using a format string (like for python's `re.sub`)

Answer (score 0):

Most regex engines don't support variable-length expressions for lookbehind assertions.

Comment: It's only the lookbehind that's problematic. Lookahead can be anything in all regex engines that support it.