# RegEx with character set inside positive lookbehind, Is it possible?

Tags: php, regex, directory-structure, url

I need to match "name" only after "listing", but of course those words could be any url directory or page.

mydomain.com/listing/name

so the only thing I can "REGuest" (request) is to be some parent directory there.
In other words, I want to match the "position" i.e. whatever comes 2nd after the domain.

I'm trying something like

```
(?<=mydomain\.com/[^/\?&]+/)[^/\?&]+(?:/)?
```

But the character set won't work inside the positive lookbehind, at least it's setup to match only ONE character. As soon as I try to match other than one (e.g. modify it with +, ? or *) it just stops working.

I'm obviously missing the positive lookbehind syntax and it seems not intended for what I'm trying.

How can I match that 2nd level filename?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) states that

> The bad news is that most regex flavors do not allow you to use just
>   any regex inside a lookbehind, because they cannot apply a regular
>   expression backwards. Therefore, the regular expression engine needs
>   to be able to figure out how many steps to step back before checking
>   the lookbehind...

(Read further, they even mention Perl, Python and Java.)

I think the quantifier might be the problem. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or) on stackoverflow and briefly flew over it.

Wouldn't it be possible to just match the whole path, and use a group for the second level filename:

```
mydomain\.com\/[^\/\?&]+\/([^\/\?&]+)(?:\/)?
```

(note: I had to escape the / for my tests...)

The result of this would be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mydomain.com/listing/name
    [1] => name
)
```

Now, because I don't know the context of your problem, I just assumed you would be able to postprocess the results and get the group 1 (index 1) from the result. If not, I unfortunately don't know...