# strip out <p> tags which is inside another tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to strip out `<p>` tags which is inside a pre tag, How can i do this in php?  My code will be like this:

```
<pre class="brush:php;">
<p>Guna</p><p>Sekar</p>
</pre>
```

I need text inside `<p>` tags, need to remove only `<p>` `</p>` tag.

Comment: What is the HTML you have and the code you want? I probably see only the HTML you have.

Comment: And how does the text look after you got it? You probably are not keen on the string `GunaSekar`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a single regex, this was tested in powershell but should work for most regex which supports look arounds

```
$string = '<pre class="brush:php;"><p>Guna</p><p>Sekar</p></pre><pre class="brush:php;"><p>Point</p><p>Miner</p></pre>'
$String -replace '(?<=<pre.*?>[^>]*?)(?!</pre)(<p>|</p>)(?=.*?</pre)', ""
```

Yields

```
<pre class="brush:php;">GunaSekar</pre><pre class="brush:php;">PointMiner</pre>
```

Dissecting the regex:

1. the first lookahead validates there is a pre tag before the current match
2. the second lookaround validates there was no /pre tag between the pre tag and the match
3. test for both p and /p
4. look around to ensure there is a closing /pre tag

Comment: i'm getting **Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 18 error** when i execute this pattern. my code is like this: `$conv=preg_replace('/(?<=<pre.*?>[^>]*?)(?!<\/pre)(<p>|<\/p>)(?=.*?<\/pre)/is', '',$sample);`

Comment: > Many regular expression libraries do only allow strict expressions to be used in look behind assertions like: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or 

However, pick "ecmascript / javascript " in https://regex101.com/ should work.

Or you can use a software called Calibre > convert book > Look & Feel > Transform HTML > "If the tag is `pre p` Remove tag only"

Answer (score 0):

You could use basic Regexp.

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
<pre class="brush:php;">
<p>Guna</p><p>Sekar</p>
</pre>
STR;
echo preg_replace("/<[ ]*p( [^>]*)?>|<\/[ ]*p[ ]*>/i", " ", $str);
```

Comment: probably like `/<[ ]*p[^>]*>|<\/[ ]*p[ ]*>/i` just to cover all cases, but this would still strip pre tags however...

Comment: `/<[ ]*p( [^>]*)?>|<\/[ ]*p[ ]*>/i` so? force at least one whitespace to differentiate p and pre

Comment: I wonder why there is zero or infinite space in an actual HTML tag like this: `<p` or `< p`. The latter is no valid tag, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. It runs 2 regex commands to list all the <p> tags inside <pre> tags.

```
preg_match('/<pre .*?>(.*?)<\/pre>/s', $string, $matches1);
preg_match_all('/<p>.*?<\/p>/', $matches1[1], $ptags);
```

The matching <p> tags will be available in $ptags array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to match everything that's in a `<pre>` tag and then use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip-tags) to remove all html tags:

```
$html = '<pre class="brush:php;">
<p>Guna</p><p>Sekar</p>
</pre>
';

$removed_tags = preg_replace_callback('#(<pre[^>]*>)(.+?)(</pre>)#is', function($m){
    return($m[1].strip_tags($m[2]).$m[3]);
}, $html);
var_dump($removed_tags);
```

**Note this works only with PHP 5.3+**

Answer (score 0):

It looked like simple work, but it took hours to find a way. This is what i done:

- Downloaded [simple dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm) from source forge
- Traversed each `<pre>` tag and strip out `<p>` tags
- Rewrite the content into `<pre>` tag
- Retrive modified content

Here is full code:

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$text='<pre class="brush:php;"><p>Guna</p><p>Sekar</p></pre>';
$html = str_get_html($text);
$strip_chars=array('<p>','</p>');
foreach($html->find('pre') as $element){
  $code = $element->getAttribute('innertext');
  $code=str_replace($strip_chars,'',$code);
  $element->setAttribute('innertext',$code);
}
echo $html->root->innertext();
```

This will output:

```
<pre class="brush:php;">GunaSekar</pre>
```

Thanks for all your suggestions.