# Regular expression using negative lookbehind not working in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I have a source file with literally hundreds of occurrences of strings `flecha.jpg` and `flecha1.jpg`, but I need to find occurrences of any other `.jpg` image (i.e. `casa.jpg`, `moto.jpg`, whatever)

I have tried using a regular expression with negative lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<!flecha|flecha1).jpg
```

but it doesn't work! Notepad++ simply says that it is an invalid regular expression.

I have tried the regex elsewhere and it works, [here is an example](http://regexr.com?35b6c) so I guess it is a problem with NPP's handling of regexes or with the syntax of lookbehinds/lookaheads.

So how could I achieve the same regex result in NPP?

If useful, I am using Notepad++ version 6.3 Unicode

As an extra, if you are so kind, what would be the syntax to achieve the same thing but with optional numbers (in this case only '1') as a suffix of my string? (even if it doesn't work in NPP, just to know)...

I tried `(?<!flecha[1]?).jpg` but it doesn't work. It should work the same as the other regex, see here ([RegExr](http://regexr.com?35b6f))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Notepad++ seems to **not have implemented variable-length look-behinds** (this happens with some tools). A workaround is to use more than one fixed-length look-behind:

```
(?<!flecha)(?<!flecha1)\.jpg
```

As you can check, [the matches are the same](https://regex101.com/r/tP0eY5/1). But this works with npp.

Notice I escaped the `.`, since you are trying to match extensions, what you want is the literal `.`. The way you had, it was a wildcard - could be any character.

About the extra question, unfortunately, as we can't have variable-length look-behinds, it is not possible to have optional suffixes (numbers) without having multiple look-behinds.

Comment: On a brighter note, you can use `[0-9]`, `\d` or others alike, as long as the length of each look-behind remains fixed: `(?<!flecha)(?<!flecha[1-3])\.jpg`

Comment: Dug a little more and got a confirmation on what we thought: Notepad++ uses Boost as regex implementation and Boost Regex only supports fixed-length lookbehinds.

Comment: Excelent! Just a little doubt regarding your answer; the restriction of not having variable-length look-behinds, applies in this case, only to Npp? or for Regex and other tools too? i.e. in other tools I maybe could use variable-length look-behinds? Or is it a RegEx restriction and won't work anywhere else?

Comment: It's not a restriction to regex in general. I mean, a tool/language can have variable-length look-behinds, it just depends on them. For NPP right now, it is a restriction. See, npp before 6.3 didn't have look-behinds at all. It is quite new for them. Other tools have their own history. Perl version 5 and below also didn't have variable-length look-behinds, in the more recent versions they do. JavaScript does not have look-behinds at all, while Java has variable-length look-behinds where the max length can be known before hand (`(?<=[a|abc])` would be ok, but `(?<=a|.*)` would not).

Comment: Also, as you only want to match the extension, your only resource/possibility is look-behind. If you could match other parts (and maybe use replace with a group to put them back), there is the possibility of simpler regexes.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought all, or at least most of tools should have the same "rules" for implementing regular expressions, but as I see, that's not the case, and they can have different restrictions. That's a shame. It should be standard, to ensure a regex can work anywhere. Thanks for the thorough answer/comments!

Comment: @acdcjunior you might want to add that bit about using Boost to your answer.

Answer (score 18):

## Solving the problem of the variable-length-negative-lookbehind limitation in Notepad++

Given here are several strategies for working around this limitation in Notepad++ (or any regex engine with the same limitation)

## Defining the problem

Notepad++ does not support the use of variable-length negative lookbehind assertions, and it would be nice to have some workarounds. Let's consider the example in the original question, but assume we want to avoid occurrences of files named `flecha` with *any* number of digits after `flecha`, and with any characters before `flecha`. In that case, a regex utilizing a variable-length negative lookbehind would look like `(?<!flecha[0-9]*)\.jpg`.

#### Strings we *don't* want to match in this example

- `flecha.jpg`
- `flecha1.jpg`
- `flecha00501275696.jpg`
- `aflecha.jpg`
- `img_flecha9.jpg`
- `abcflecha556677.jpg`

---

## The Strategies

1. #### Inserting Temporary Markers

   Begin by performing a find-and-replace on the instances that you want to avoid working with - in our case, instances of `flecha[0-9]*\.jpg`. Insert a special marker to form a pattern that doesn't appear anywhere else. For this example, we will insert an extra `.` before `.jpg`, assuming that `..jpg` doesn't appear elsewhere. So we do:

   Find: `(flecha[0-9]*)(\.jpg)`

   Replace with: `$1.$2`

   Now you can search your document for all the other `.jpg` filenames with a simple regex like `\w+\.jpg` or `(?<!\.)\.jpg` and do what you want with them. When you're done, do a final find-and-replace operation where you replace all instances of `..jpg` with `.jpg`, to remove the temporary marker.
2. #### Using a negative lookahead assertion

   A negative lookahead assertion can be used to make sure that you're not matching the undesired file names:

   `(?<!\S)(?!\S*flecha\d*\.jpg)\S+\.jpg`

   Breaking it down:

   - `(?<!\S)` ensures that your match begins at the start of a file name, and not in the middle, by asserting that your match is not preceded by a non-whitespace character.
   - `(?!\S*flecha\d*\.jpg)` ensures that whatever is matched does not contain the pattern we want to avoid
   - `\S+\.jpg` is what actually gets matched -- a string of non-whitespace characters followed by `.jpg`.
3. #### Using multiple fixed-length negative lookbehinds

   This is a quick (but not-so-elegant) solution for situations where the pattern you don't want to match has a **small number of possible lengths**.

   For example, if we know that `flecha` is only followed by up to three digits, our regex could be:

   `(?<!flecha)(?<!flecha[0-9])(?<!flecha[0-9][0-9])(?<!flecha[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.jpg`

Comment: Your Strategy 3 absolutely saved my day. I know that sending thanks isn't the intended purpose of comments, but I thought I'd post regardless. Thanks @JoshWithee! To anyone else who is grapplling with variable-length lookaheads/lookbehinds, I recommend trying this inelegant but effective approach.

Comment: Strategy 1 helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that you're only matching (in the sense of *consuming*) the extension (`.jpg`)?  I would think you wanted to match the whole filename, no?  And that's much easier to do with a lookahead:

```
\b(?!flecha1?\b)\w+\.jpg
```

The first `\b` anchors the match to the beginning of the name (assuming it's really a filename we're looking at).  Then `(?!flecha1?\b)` asserts that the name is not `flecha` or `flecha1`.   Once that's done, the `\w+` goes ahead and consumes the name.  Then `\.jpg` grabs the extension to finish off the match.

Comment: As you noticed, I only want to match the .jpg extension. I only wanted to look for any other images in a source file, and i don't need to know their file names, only if they occur at all. But thanks! the answer surely will be useful for the future =)