# In Notepad++ regex to remove varying number of spaces in multiple instances of a substring

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++,
I would like to replace all occurrences of a semi-colon followed by a space (`"; "`) with a semi-colon (`";"`) in a string like this

```
S#14_Budget.Y#2014; 2015; 2016.P{[Third Generation]}.w#Periodic.E{PRU.[Descendants]}; CNS.PRU.V#[None]; Total.A{Asset.[Base]}; {Liab.[Base]}; {NProfit.[Base]}; {Bal.[Base]}; {Stats.[Base]}; {BalSht.[Base]}; {NIncome.[Base]}.I{[ICP Top].[Base]}.C1#TotalC1.C2#TotalC2.C3#[None].C4#[None]</ns
```

The string can  occur hundreds of times in one file, and I find it using `S#.*</ns`.
The string always begins with `S#` and always ends with `</ns`.
All the bits in the middle can vary, including the number of spaces.
Only the `"; "` needs to be changed to `";"`.

Comment: ["Notepad++ seems to not have implemented variable-length look-behinds"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286667/error-in-regular-expression-in-notepad-using-negative-lookbehind) (at least not when that was written, according to random-stranger-on-the-internet) - this might make this rather difficult / impossible (otherwise replacing `(?<=S#14.*?); (?=.*?</ns)` with `;` would've worked).

Comment: @Dukeling We could use `S#14.*?\K; (?=.*?</ns)`, but that means we need to replace several times, that could be solved using macros :P

Comment: @HamZa, `S#14.*?\K; (?=.*?</ns)` finds the item to be replaced; Just have to run it repeatedly until no items found. ...seems that will be faster than doing it in a GUI

Comment: @HamZa Since there is a `Replace All`, you can just hit that as many times as the string containing the most `; `'s, if this isn't too great a number, but a macro isn't too difficult either. It doesn't want to replace with `\K`, but you can use grouping, posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of help from [HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza), I came up with this:

Replace:

```
(S#.*?;) (?=.*?</ns)
```

with:

```
\1
```

Then just hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> until no replacements are made any more (each find includes the `S#`, so you can only do one replacement for each of these strings at a time), or you can write a simple macro to find and replace (all?) and run that as many times as required.

If this string of yours is on its own line, you should also include start (`^`) and end (`$`) of line indicators:

```
^(S#.*?;) (?=.*?</ns$)
```

**Explained:** ([source](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28S%23.*%3F%3B%29+%28%3F%3D.*%3F%3C%2Fns%29))

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    S#                       'S#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </ns                     '</ns'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

If Notepad++ supported variable-length look-behinds (at least it doesn't in 6.4.5), you could've replaced `(?<=S#14.*?); (?=.*?</ns)` with `;` (and just have done one <kbd>Replace All</kbd>).

Comment: doesn't work work for me at all(( "Can't find any expression"