# Python regex match after > using positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to match

```
something something bar<TEST> blah blah </TEST> foo
```

I want to extract the foo and I'm using this regex

```
(?<=</\w+>)(\s\w)
```

why isn't that working? I get an empty list. I get this error-

```
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says -- `\w` can match any arbitrary amount of content, so you can't use it for lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot quite use lookarounds here, since the ideal one to use would be a positive lookbehind and ensure there's something like `</\w+>` behind. In C#, you could have used something like `(?<=</\w+>)(\s*\w+)`, but variable width lookbehinds are not supported by python. What's left to do is perhaps to include the `</\w+>` in the match and use a capture group:

```
</[^<>]*>\s*(\w+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN4lU7).

Note that `[^<>]` is usually safer when between `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want a lookbehind, but unfortunately [not many libraries support quantifiers in a lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or). You also have a couple errors/typos:

```
(?<=</\w+>)\s*(\w+)
```