# Variable-Width Lookbehind Issue in Python

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

I got the following scenarios:

```
1) car on the right shoulder
2) car on the left shoulder
3) car on the shoulder
```

I want to match "shoulder" when left|right is not present. So only 3) return "shoulder"

```
re.compile(r'(?<!right|right\s*)shoulder')
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

It seems like I can't use \s* and "|"

How can I solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I needed to use the regex `r'(?<=^i?bs=).+'`, I ended up going with `r'^i?bs=(.+)'` and just accessed the first group instead. Sometimes it's pretty easy to work around this limitation.

Comment: Just to clarify the comment above, which was the solution for me: instead of using a look-behind, add the expression in the main statement, but surround the portion you want to extract with parenthesis to create a match group. It is available as `match.group(1)`, index zero being the whole match.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### `regex` module: variable-width lookbehind

In addition to the [answer by HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987479/1078583), for any regex of any complexity in Python, I recommend using the outstanding [`regex` module by Matthew Barnett](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). It supports infinite lookbehind—one of the few engines to do so, along with .NET and JGSoft.

This allows you to do for instance:

```
import regex
if regex.search("(?<!right |left )shoulder", "left shoulder"):
    print("It matches!")
else:
    print("Nah... No match.")
```

You could also use `\s+` if you wished.

**Output:**

```
Nah... No match.
```

Comment: +1 for the great regex module link. Do we have something similar available for PHP?

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. In PHP I don't know another engine—you know the usual workarounds to infinite lookbehind, `\K` in some cases, capture groups in others.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great regex link. regex module supports infinite lookbehind/lookahead. Wow.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using positive lookbehind with <= rather than negative lookbehind with <!

Answer (score 2):

In most regex engines, lookbehinds needs to be of fixed width. This means you can't use quantifiers in a lookbehind in Python `+*?`. The solution is to move `\s*` outside your lookbehind:

```
(?<!left|right)\s*shoulder
```

You will notice that this expression matches every combination. So we need to change the quantifier from `*` to `+`:

```
(?<!left|right)\s+shoulder
```

The only problem with this solution is that it won't find `shoulder` if it's at the beginning of the string, so we might add an alternative with an anchor:

```
^shoulder|(?<!left|right)\s+shoulder
```

If you want to get rid of the whitespaces just use the strip function.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mW6yC3/1)</kbd>

Comment: regex.compile(r'(?<!left|right)\s+shoulder').findall("this is right       shoulder")
['      shoulder']  this still returns shoulder. I guess I have to use regex module with infinet lookbehind

Comment: @EdwardWang Not sure what's going on on your side but here [it works as expected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LtZ8x.png)

Comment: @HamZa you misunderstood my question. When right/left presents before "shoulder", I expect not match.But your solution still returns shoulder back, and it's nothing different than r'/bshoulder/b'

Comment: @EdwardWang Have you checked the image I linked? It doesn't return "shoulder" when there is "right" or "left" behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The need for variable width look-behind can be avoided by combining a fixed-width positive look-behind with a negative look-ahead:

```python
re.split('(?<=[\u4e00-\u9fff])(?![\u4e00-\u9fff])', '缩头乌龟suō tóu wūguī', 1)
# >>> Out[47]: ['缩头乌龟', 'suō tóu wūguī']
```