# Positive lookbehind regex obvious maximum length

Tags: java, regex

So I have been experimenting with regex in order to parse the following strings:

```
INFO: Device 6: Time 20.11.2015 06:28:00 - [Script] FunFehlerButton: Execute [0031 text]    
and    
INFO: Device 0: Time 09.12.2015 03:51:44 - [Replication] FunFehlerButton: Execute    
and    
INFO: Device 6: Time 20.11.2015 06:28:00 - FunFehlerButton: Execute
```

The regex I tried to use are:

```
(?<=\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} - ).*
```

and

```
(?<=\\[\\w*\\]).*
```

of which the first one runs correctly and the second one lands in a expcetion.

My goal is to get the text "FunFehlerButton: Execute ...".

I hope someone can hint me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, there is the page [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) where you can create regex from a string.

Comment: So: https://regex101.com/r/mF7kH7/1

Comment: @JorgeCampos, he wants some dots at the end too.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java supports variable length lookbehind only if the size is limited and the subpattern in the lookbehind isn't too complicated.

In short, you can't write:

```
(?<=\\[\\w*\\]).*
```

But you can write:

```
(?<=\\[\\w{0,1000}\\]).*
```

However something like:

```
(?<=\\[(?:\\w{0,2}){0,500}\\w?\\]).*
```

doesn't work since the max length isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support variable length expression in lookbehind.

You can instead use this regex:

```
String re = "(?:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} - (?:\\[[^\\]]*\\] )?)([\\w: -]+)";
```

And use captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE3mO8/1)