# REGEX: Negative lookbehind with multiple whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

```regex
(?<!egg[\n*\s*])(yolk)
```

```
eggyolk  #pass
egg yolk   #notpass
egg                                   yolk #pass
```

How I can make sure the third string does not get passed as I made sure it looked behind multiple whitespace characters and new-lines.

Comment: @dvo https://regex101.com/r/FvgoOF/1 I get a pattern error

Comment: What is your regex platform?

Comment: You have selected python on regex101. I think `(?<!egg\s+)yolk` will work with the python regex module https://pypi.org/project/regex/

Comment: @anubhava python

Comment: @Thefourthbird that did not work

Comment: So why not use positive lookbehind e.g. `(?<=\begg)yolk`

Comment: @md123 See https://rextester.com/XHQ48818 You could select javascript on regex101 (which is not the same engine but gives the same result) https://regex101.com/r/BtmB4C/1 Note that `\s` also matches `\n`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's exactly what i want, but i'm using python

Comment: @md123 That will work if you use the regex module https://pypi.org/project/regex/ You could also try the suggestion of anubhava

Comment: Python `re` solution is `[y for x,y in re.findall(r"(egg\s+)?(yolk)", text) if not x]`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502597/3832970) hints at this way of solving the issue.