# Regular Expression To Match Header Tags Not In Specific Div

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I have PHP code that puts out HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>This is a header</h2>
<h2>This is one too/h2>
<h4>Here's one</h4>
<div class="ignore">
<h5>I'm one in here too</h5>
</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is preg_match_all of the header tags. My regular expression `(<h([1-6]{1})[^>]*)>.*<\/h\2>` returns all of them appropriately, but I don't want to grab the headers that are in the div with the class "ignore". I was reading about negative lookaheads, but it gets tricky. Anyone with help will be appreciated.

Desired output:

```
<h2>This is a header</h2>
<h2>This is one too/h2>
<h4>Here's one</h4>
```

Note I'm one in here too is omitted because it's wrapped in div with class "ignore".

Comment: If it is an option, use  DOMDocument for example instead of a regex

Comment: Lookbehinds / lookaheads sound like the right direction. What have you tried with those so far and what is your precise problem with them? People on SO will not code for you

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to code for me. I'm looking for a possible solution. The RE is written to grab the headers like I want. I just don't understand where to place the qualifiers to omit the header tags within the ignore div.

Comment: Can you share the desired output?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis edited above for desired output.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you specify you want to do it with preg_match(), here is an example of a negative look-behind (i.e. filters out those occurrences NOT preceded by XYZ) : https://regex101.com/r/FeAsuj/1

The lookbehind itself is `(?<!<div class=\"ignore\">)` .

But in the test-snippet, notice how :

- the regex depends on the exact use of whitespace ...
- ... so a platform-dependant \r\n can break the regex
- the lookbehind cannot have a variable length, i.e. \n? - see [Regular Expression Lookbehind doesn't work with quantifiers ('+' or '*')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or)

If you MUST continue to work with regex's, consider a 2-step approach :

- step 1, you use preg_replace() to eliminate all unwanted  sections.
- step 2, use your existing regex.

In general, I would concur with the other posters to avoid regex, and go with a HTML parser.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to hep me with the lookbehind. I was beating myself in the head with the lookahead and thanks for not veering me off my path.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess around with regular expressions here - unleash the power of `DOMDocument` in combination with `xpath` queries:

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOT
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>This is a header</h2>
<h2>This is one too</h2>
<h4>Here's one</h4>
<div class="ignore">
<h5>I'm one in here too</h5>
</div>
</div>
EOT;

$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$headers = $xpath->query("
    //div[not(contains(@class, 'ignore'))]
    /*[self::h2 or self::h4 or self::h5]");

foreach ($headers as $header) {
    echo $header->nodeValue . "\n";
}

?>
```

This will yield

```
This is a header
This is one too
Here's one
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll use this solution next go.

Answer (score 2):

With `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>This is a header</h2>
<h2>This is one too</h2>
<h4>Here's one</h4>
<div class="ignore">
<h5>I'm one in here too</h5>
</div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query('
//*
[contains(";h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;", concat(";", local-name(), ";"))]
[not(ancestor::div[
    contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " ignore ")
    ])
]');

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    echo 'tag name: ', $node->nodeName, PHP_EOL,
         'html content: ', $dom->saveHTML($node), PHP_EOL,
         'text content: ', $node->textContent, PHP_EOL,
         PHP_EOL;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/pdjNd)

If you aren't comfortable with XPath take a look at the [zvon tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll use this the next time for sure.