# Regex pattern alternative for (negative) lookbehinds of arbitrary, non-zero length

Tags: regex

I lack experience with regex and need help with this problem:

**Objective:** Create a regex pattern that matches "renal" or "kidney" in an arbitrary string only if it does not contain "carcinoma".

**Example strings:**

1. "Renal cell carcinoma"
2. "Clear cell carcinoma of kidney"
3. "Chronic renal impairment"

**Expected output:** The regex pattern does not match "renal" and "kidney" in the first two strings; it does match "renal" in the third string (since there is no "carcinoma").

**What I've tried:** (?<!carcinoma).*(kidney|renal). I stopped here because it didn't work — because, as I've learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or) and [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind), lookbehinds are limited to basically non-zero length; regular expressions cannot be applied backwards an arbitrary length.

So what regex pattern will do the trick? I want a pattern that maintains focus on (or is "anchored" on) "renal" and "kidney" and not "carcinoma".

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead from the start of the string `^(?!.*\bcarcinoma\b).*\b(renal|kidney)\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/1FVdio/1

Comment: That works, thank you very much! Let me make sure I understand it: it anchors at the start of the string (with ^); does a nonzero-length, negative lookahead for carcinoma, followed by the inclusion of renal or kidney.

Comment: Yes, if by "inclusion" you mean it matches "renal" or "kidney" preceded (from the start of the string) by zero or more characters. Without the anchor, for the string `"my kidney is great"` the negative lookahead would be satisfied, after which the regex's pointer would be between the `"k"` and `"i"` of `"kidney"`, because from that location `"kidney"` does not appear in the rest of the string. Hence the need for the anchor.

Comment: In general, to assert the string *does not* contain a specific string, as here, use a negative lookahead with the anchor `^` (or possibly `\A`, depending on the language and application). To assert the string *does* contain a specific string, use a positive lookahead with the same anchor.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried `(?<!carcinoma).*(kidney|renal)` asserts what is directly to the left is not `carcinoma` which is true from the start of the string.

Then it will match any char 0+ times until the end of the string and tries to backtrack to fit in either kidney or renal.

---

Instead of using `(?<!carcinoma)`, use `^(?!.*\bcarcinoma\b)` to assert from the start of the string that `bcarcinoma` is not present at the right.

Then match either the word renal or kidney in the string.

```
^(?!.*\bcarcinoma\b).*\b(renal|kidney)\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/blg2MP/1)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!