# Erase everything following a known string of variating length with regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a bunch of strings of car models:

```
vec <- c("2010 mercedes-benz sl500r",
     "2010 mercedes-benz e550",
     "2010 mercedes-benz glk350",
     "2010 mercedes-benz c300w",
     "2010 mercedes-benz 300")
```

I want to remove everything that is after the first n letters of the model name so here is the wanted output:

```
c("2010 mercedes-benz sl",
  "2020 mercedes-benz e",
  "2017 mercedes-benz glk",
  "2013 mercedes-benz c",
  "2014 mercedes-benz 300")
```

The problem is that even if the make is the same, `mercedes-benz`, model names do not always have the same structure.  Meaning that they can start with 0 to 3 letters, and can finish with a letter or not.  I want to remove everything that follows the letters, if there are any.

I've tried:

```
gsub("(?<=benz\\s\\D)\\w*", "", vec, perl=T)
```

But it doesn't deal with multiple letters models and this:

```
gsub("(?<=benz\\s\\D*)\\w*", "", vec, perl=T)
```

Is not proper in regex for a reason explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or) but not quite all understood.

Any idea how to solve this?

I work in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a TRE based regex with `gsub` like

```r
gsub("(benz\\s+[[:alpha:]]+)\\d\\w*", "\\1", vec)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kez8L/1).

**Details**

- `(benz\s+[[:alpha:]]+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `benz`, one or more whitespace, and one or more letters
- `\d` - a digit
  -`\w*` - zero or more letters, digits or `_`.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/i7IePu):

```
vec <- c("2010 mercedes-benz sl500r",
     "2010 mercedes-benz e550",
     "2010 mercedes-benz glk350",
     "2010 mercedes-benz c300w",
     "2010 mercedes-benz 300")
gsub("(benz\\s+[[:alpha:]]+)\\d\\w*", "\\1", vec)
```

Output:

```
[1] "2010 mercedes-benz sl"  "2010 mercedes-benz e"   "2010 mercedes-benz glk"
[4] "2010 mercedes-benz c"   "2010 mercedes-benz 300"
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps.  Specify the regex lookaround to to capture the lower case letters (`([a-z]+)`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`)

```
sub("(?<=benz )([a-z]+).*", "\\1",   vec, perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#[1] "2010 mercedes-benz sl"  "2010 mercedes-benz e" 
#[3] "2010 mercedes-benz glk" "2010 mercedes-benz c"  
#[5] "2010 mercedes-benz 300"
```

**Details**

1. `(?<=benz )`) - regex lookaround checks for benz followed by a space
2. `([a-z]+)` - capture one or more letters as a group
3. `\\1` - replacement backreference for the captured group

#### data

```
vec <- c("2010 mercedes-benz sl500r",
     "2010 mercedes-benz e550",
     "2010 mercedes-benz glk350",
     "2010 mercedes-benz c300w",
     "2010 mercedes-benz 300")
```